# Accumulator Generator test - Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

Paul Graham, in his great article [Revenge of the Nerds](http://www.paulgraham.com/icad.html), claimed that languages vary in power. He mentioned a nice exercise - writing an accumulator generator:

> We want to write a function that generates accumulators-- a function
>   that takes a number n, and returns a function that takes another
>   number i and returns n incremented by i.

Solution in Java is

```java
public class Accumulator {

    public interface Inttoint {
        public int call(int i);
    }

    public static Inttoint foo(final int n) {
        return new Inttoint() {
            int s = n;
            public int call(int i) {
                s = s + i;
                return s;
            }};
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Inttoint accumulator = foo(1);

        System.out.println(accumulator.call(2) == 3);
        System.out.println(accumulator.call(3) == 6);
    }

}
```

I am curious, whether in **Java 8** (thanks to lambda) is already some elegant way how to write it similarly to Groovy, see below. I tried `Function<Integer, Integer>`

But I stuck with this compiler error.

> local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or
>   effectively final

So do you have some Java 8 solution?

Compare the old Java solution with the Groovy one

```
def foo(n) {
    return {n += it}
}

def accumulator = foo(1)
assert accumulator(2) == 3
assert accumulator(3) == 6
```

Comment: See also PG's catalog of accumulator generators in different languages: http://www.paulgraham.com/accgen.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, you can still use all the new Java 8 interfaces using anonymous class syntax instead of lambda syntax. For example:

```
import java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator;

public class Accumulator {
    public static IntUnaryOperator foo(int n) {
        return new IntUnaryOperator() {
            private int value = n;
            @Override
            public int applyAsInt(int i) {
                return value += i;
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        IntUnaryOperator accumulator = foo(1);
        System.out.println(accumulator.applyAsInt(2)); // output: 3
        System.out.println(accumulator.applyAsInt(3)); // output: 6
    }
}
```

(Rather than [`Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html), I used [`IntUnaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntUnaryOperator.html) here as it allows the use of primitive `int`s instead of boxed `Integer`s. It's logically equivalent to `Function<int,int>`, if that were legal.)

Now, how can we shorten this bulky thing with lambda syntax? Local variables passed into lambdas are required to be (effectively) `final`. The limitation means you cannot trivially write a variable whose value accumulates between calls. The following does *not* work:

```
public static IntUnaryOperator foo(int n) {
    return i -> n += i; // nope, sorry!
}
```

We can work around the limitation by **using some mutable object as a holder** for the current accumulator value. A one-element array can be used for this. The array *variable* is not changing – only the contents of the array object it points at are changing, so the array variable is effectively final and this is allowed:

```
public static IntUnaryOperator foo(int n) {
    int[] value = new int[] { n };
    return i -> value[0] += i;
}
```

Any object with a mutable field can potentially be used as a holder. As suggested below by @andersschuller, an [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) fits well here, and makes the returned functions thread-safe:

```
public static IntUnaryOperator foo(int n) {
    AtomicInteger value = new AtomicInteger(n);
    return i -> value.addAndGet(i);
}
```

And @srborlongan points out this can be re-written using a method reference, which is even shorter (though not more readable):

```
public static IntUnaryOperator foo(int n) {
    return new AtomicInteger(n)::addAndGet;
}
```

Comment: +1 Just curious, what is the purpose of using an array to (as far as I can see) make a copy of n?

Comment: I would probably suggest replacing the array with an [`AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html), or maybe even the [`LongAdder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/LongAdder.html) added in Java 8.

Comment: @Boann It works, but I am disappointed that there is not more elegant way.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo Because you cannot change n in the lambda. The variable must be (effectively) final. But you can make a final variable point at some object, such as an array, which has non-final elements or fields.

Comment: @Boann Maybe add an example of using your `Accumulator` in a stream, for example `IntStream.rangeClosed (1,3).forEach (accumulator::apply)`?  Up to you.

Comment: `foo(int)` may also be simply defined as `return new AtomicInteger(n)::addAndGet;`, though I am sure that such code may not be as readable as the original (which does the same thing: create an AtomicInteger instance from the given integer, then encapsulate the instance's addAndGet method (possibly as a Function<Integer, Integer> or UnaryOperator<Integer> or IntUnaryOperator)).

Comment: @srborlongan Woah amazing!