# Why can I not reference the variable from within a lambda in this case?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have got the following code, which is somewhat abstracted from a real implementation I had in a Java program:

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String line;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    String lineReference = line;
    runLater(() -> consumeString(lineReference));
}
```

Here I need to use a reference copy for the lambda expression, when I try to use `line` I get:

> Local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final

It seems rather awkward to me, as all I do to fix it is obtain a new reference to the object, this is something the compiler could also figure out by itself.

So I would say `line` is *effectively final* here, as it only gets the assignment in the loop and nowhere else.

Could anyone shed some more light on this and explain why exactly it is needed here and why the compile cannot fix it?

Comment: Why don't you use [BufferedReader::lines](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#lines--)?

Comment: @nosid Does it work on a stream that can be left open?

Comment: "final" or "effectively final" mean the value is assigned once and never changed after that.  `line` is assigned multiple times (once for each time a new line is read).  You must have had the wrong idea about what "effectively final" means--it's not about how many *places* in the source code it's assigned, but rather about whether it could be reassigned while the program is running.

Comment: Voting to reopen because the question that this was supposed to be a duplicate of was actually answering a different question.

Comment: Its not effectively final, because it get set more the once. As you copy the reference to `lineReference` you put that on stack frame. And this is not changed.

Comment: @swiki: Can you explain, why the stream should be left open?

Comment: I could compile comparable code successfully with 1.8.0_05

Comment: Ah, now that I read this code again, I think it *is* the duplicate of the original, as the code given *does* compile.

Comment: @nosid Because I am reading from `System.in` and I want to react on any input that is to follow.

Comment: The effectively final means that you can declare the variable as **`final`** without any change to the code. Your example works with or without `final` whereas your original code would not have compiled with `final`. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20940888/918959).

Comment: There won't be any "input that is to follow" because you don't get null from `readLine` until you hit EOF. The read will block rather than returning null in cases where there is no input currently available.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java lambda - for loop counter is not effectively final](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24893597/java-lambda-for-loop-counter-is-not-effectively-final)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> So I would say `line` is *effectively final* here, as it only gets the assignment in the loop and nowhere else.

No, it's not final because during the variable's lifetime it is getting assigned a new value on every loop iteration. This is the complete opposite of final.

> I get: 'Local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final'. It seems rather awkward to me.

Consider this: You're passing the lambda to `runLater(...)`. When the lambda finally executes, which value of `line` should it use? The value it had when the lambda was created, or the value it had when the lambda executed?

The rule is that lambdas (appear to) use the current value at time of lambda execution. They do not (appear to) create a copy of the variable. Now, how is this rule implemented in practice?

- If `line` is a static field, it's easy because there is no state for the lambda to capture. The lambda can read the current value of the field whenever it needs to, just as any other code can.
- If `line` is an instance field, that's also *fairly* easy. The lambda can capture the reference to the object in a private hidden field in each lambda object, and access the `line` field through that.
- If `line` is a local variable within a method (as it is in your example), this is suddenly *not* easy. At an implementation level, the lambda expression [is in a completely different method](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-translation.html), and there is no easy way for outside code to share access to the variable which only exists within the one method.

To enable access to the local variable, the compiler would have to box the variable into some hidden, mutable holder object (such as a 1-element array) so that the holder object could be referenced from both the enclosing method and the lambda, giving them both access to the variable within.

Although that solution would technically work, the behavior it achieves would be undesirable for a bundle of reasons. Allocating the holder object would give local variables an unnatural performance characteristic which would not be obvious from reading the code. (Merely defining a lambda that used a local variable would make the variable slower throughout the method.) Worse than that, it would introduce subtle race conditions into otherwise simple code, depending on when the lambda is executed. In your example, by the time the lambda executes, any number of loop iterations could have happened, or the method might have returned, so the `line` variable could have any value or no defined value, and almost certainly wouldn't have the value you wanted. So in practice you'd *still* need the separate, unchanging `lineReference` variable! The only difference is that the compiler wouldn't require you do to that, so it would allow you to write broken code. Since the lambda could ultimately execute on a different thread, this would also introduce subtle concurrency and thread visibility complexity to local variables, which would require the language to allow the `volatile` modifier on local variables, and other bother.

So, for the lambda to see the current changing values of local variables would introduce a lot of fuss (and no advantages since [you can do the mutable holder trick manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24083215) if you ever need to). Instead, the language says no to the whole kerfuffle by simply demanding that the variable be `final` (or effectively final). That way, the lambda can capture the value of the local variable at lambda creation time, and it doesn't need to worry about detecting changes because it knows there can't be any.

> This is something the compiler could also figure out by itself

It did figure it out, which is why it disallows it. The `lineReference` variable **is of absolutely no benefit to the compiler**, which could easily capture the current value of `line` for use in the lambda at each lambda object's creation time. But since the lambda wouldn't detect changes to the variable (which would be impractical and undesirable for the reasons explained above), the subtle difference between capture of fields and capture of locals would be confusing. The "final or effectively final" rule is for the programmer's benefit: it prevents you from wondering why changes to a variable don't appear within a lambda, by preventing you from changing them at all. Here's an example of what would happen without that rule:

```
String field = "A";
void foo() {
    String local = "A";
    Runnable r = () -> System.out.println(field + local);
    field = "B";
    local = "B";
    r.run(); // output: "BA"
}
```

That confusion goes away if any local variables referenced within the lambda are (effectively) final.

In your code, `lineReference` *is* effectively final. Its value is assigned *exactly once* during its lifetime, before it goes out of scope at the end of each loop iteration, which is why you can use it in the lambda.

There is an alternative arrangement of your loop possible by declaring `line` inside the loop body:

```
for (;;) {
    String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
    if (line == null) break;
    runLater(() -> consumeString(line));
}
```

This is allowed because `line` now goes out of scope at the end of each loop iteration. Each iteration effectively has a fresh variable, assigned exactly once. (However, at a low level the variable is still stored in the same CPU register, so it's not like it has to be repeatedly "created" and "destroyed". What I mean is, there is happily no extra cost to declaring variables inside a loop like this, so it's fine.)

---

Note: All this is not unique to lambdas. It also applies identically to any classes declared lexically inside the method, from which lambdas inherited the rules.

Note 2: It could be argued that lambdas would be simpler if they followed the rule of always capturing the values of variables they use at lambda creation time. Then there would be no difference in behavior between fields and locals, and no need for the "final or effectively final" rule because it would be well-established that lambdas don't see changes made after lambda creation time. But this rule would have its own uglinesses. As one example, for an instance field `x` accessed within a lambda, there would be a difference between the behavior of reading `x` (capturing final value of `x`) and `this.x` (capturing final value of `this`, seeing its field `x` changing). Language design is hard.

Comment: Nice, +1. This is closely related to the cannot-mutate-captured-nonfinal-locals issue with anonymous inner classes. The only difference in Java 8 is that such variables need not be declared `final` if they are effectively final. (This applies both to lambdas and AICs.) As such, the "effectively final" rule is merely a convenience, not a semantic change. More history in this answer from [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4732617/1441122) and this answer from [gnat](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17736622/1441122).

Answer (score 1):

If you would use `line` instead of `lineReference` in the lambda expression, you would be passing to your `runLater` method a lambda expression that would execute `consumeString` on a String referred by `line`.

But `line` keeps changing as you assign new lines to it. When you finally execute the method of the functional interface returned by the lambda expression,  only then will it get the current value of `line` and use it in the call to `consumeString`. At this point the value of `line` would not be the same as it was when you passed the lambda expression to the `runLater` method.

Comment: I think you've mixed up `line` and `lineReference`. `line` is the only variable that's changing as new lines are assigned to it. `lineReference` is not changing during its lifetime, because it's declared inside the loop body, and each loop iteration has a logically "new" `lineReference` variable.

Comment: @Boann You're right. I missed that. Thanks! Fixed it now, but your answer is still much better than mine. +1