# Java lambda - for loop counter is not effectively final

Tags: java, for-loop, lambda, java-8

Given this situation where a lambda is inside a for loop I would expect the counter i to be effectively final.

The compiler complains that i is not effectively final so I had to use i2.

```
for (int i = 0; i < x.getBooks().size(); i++){
   //The compiler needs i to be effectively final.
   int i2 = i;
   List<Book> books = bookstore.stream()
                    .filter(c -> c.getAuthors().get(i2).equals("xxx"))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

So the question is why i is not effectively final inside the scope of the for loop and is this the simplest workaround.

Comment: where are you using `i` or `i2` ?

Comment: effectively final? I'm not sure what that means. Your code doesn't even use `i` in the lambda

Comment: apologies for the typo - edited now.

Comment: This is what effectively final means http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938095/difference-between-final-and-effectively-final

Comment: IMO they should allow `final int i` which would then prevent modification of `i` outside the for construct.

Answer (score 6):

TLDR: `i` is not `final` because it is modified (`i++`) at each iteration of the `for` loop.

---

> why i is not effectively final inside the scope of the for loop ?

The `for` loop syntax is

```
for (initialization; termination; increment) {
    statement(s)
}
```

The increment expression is invoked after each iteration through the loop. In your case, increment is `i++` so `i` is modified after each iteration.

You could confirm this by declaring `i` final:

```
for (final int i = 0; i < x.getBooks().size(); i++) {
}
```

you will get this compilation error:

```
The final local variable i cannot be assigned.
It must be blank and not using a compound  assignment
```

---

> is this the simplest workaround ?

In the case of a `for` loop: yes.

But you could use a `while` loop as shown by [@dkatzel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24894705/1594933) or a `foreach`:

```
int i = 0;
for (Book book: x.getBooks()) {
    int i2 = i;
    ...  
    i++;
}
```

Comment: In your `foreach` example the semantics of `i` have been changed. It was 0 the first time around the loop. It will now be 1 the first time around. Also, the same problem with it not being effectively final exists, so `i2` would still be needed.

Answer (score 6):

As the other answers mention, `effectively final` means, that a variable only can be assigned once and will not be reassigned. That's not the case in a for-loop. `effectively final` exists, because otherwise developers have to explicitly mark a variable as `final` to use it in a lambda.

However, the reason i'm answering is a solution, to write your code without duplicating `i`:

```
IntStream.range (0, x.getBooks().size()).forEach (i -> {
    List<Book> books = bookstore.stream()
                                .filter(c -> c.getAuthors().get(i).equals("xxx"))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3)

> The scope of a local variable declared in the `ForInit` part of a basic for statement (§14.14.1) includes all of the following:
>
> - Its own initializer
> - Any further declarators to the right in the `ForInit` part of the for statement
> - The `Expression` and `ForUpdate` parts of the for statement
> - The contained Statement

And about [*effectively final*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)

> A local variable or a method, constructor, lambda, or exception
>   parameter is effectively final **if it is not declared final but it
>   never occurs as the left hand operand of an assignment operator
>   (§15.26) or as the operand of a prefix or postfix increment or
>   decrement operator**

Your `i` variable occurs as the operand of postfix increment operator

```
i++
```

It is therefore not effectively final and can not be captured by the lambda.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that a `for` loop actually equivalent to :

```
int i=0;
while(i < x.getBooks().size()){
  //execute your block
  i++;
}
```

So you see that `i` is declared only once and updated therefore not effectively final.

It's a little unclear the relationship between `x.getBooks()` and `Book.getAuthors()` but apparently they have the same size? Without a better understanding, I don't think I can show you a better way to do it.  But this might also show you that your design is poor.

Comment: The actual example is somewhat manufactured so don't worry about that too much.  The main question pertains to the scope of the counter in the for loop.

Comment: @Dan OK, then maybe the first part of my answer is sufficient?